# Retrieve all elements in nested div tags using DOM

Tags: php, xml, class, dom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><rss version="2.0" xml:base="http://www.example.com/feeds/events.xml" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" xmlns:sioc="http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#" xmlns:sioct="http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#" xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
      <channel>
        <title>Event Calendar</title>
        <link>http://www.example.com/feeds/events.xml</link>
        <description></description>
        <language>en</language>

         <item>
        <title>Thanksgiving Break 2015</title>
        <link>http://www.example.com/event/42811211</link>
        <description>&lt;div class=&quot;field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;field-items&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;field-item even&quot; property=&quot;content:encoded&quot;&gt;&lt;p&gt;Happy Holidays.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;field field-name-field-date field-type-datetime field-label-inline clearfix&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;field-label&quot;&gt;Date:&amp;nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;field-items&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;field-item even&quot;&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;date-display-single&quot; property=&quot;dc:date&quot; datatype=&quot;xsd:dateTime&quot; content=&quot;2015-11-25T00:00:00-05:00&quot;&gt;Wednesday, November 25, 2015 (All day)&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;field-item odd&quot;&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;date-display-single&quot; property=&quot;dc:date&quot; datatype=&quot;xsd:dateTime&quot; content=&quot;2015-11-26T00:00:00-05:00&quot;&gt;Thursday, November 26, 2015 (All day)&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;field-item even&quot;&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;date-display-single&quot; property=&quot;dc:date&quot; datatype=&quot;xsd:dateTime&quot; content=&quot;2015-11-27T00:00:00-05:00&quot;&gt;Friday, November 27, 2015 (All day)&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;field field-name-field-location field-type-text field-label-inline clearfix&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;field-label&quot;&gt;Location:&amp;nbsp;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;field-items&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;field-item even&quot;&gt;Blacksburg, VA&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</description>
         <pubDate>Wed, 19 Aug 2015 17:20:12 +0000</pubDate>
        <dc:creator>Cronus</dc:creator>
        <guid isPermaLink="false">311191 at http://www.example.com</guid>
        <category domain="http://www.example.com/event-categories/othermiscellaneous">Other/Miscellaneous</category>
      </item>
      </channel>
    </rss>
```

I am trying to extract all the elements embedded in the nested div tags in the XML above into an array such that all elements are extracted separately according to the type, eg: Date and Location. An ideal output would look like:

```
Title : Thanksgiving Break 2015
Link  : http://www.example.com/event/42811211
Description : Happy Holidays.
Date  : Wednesday, November 25, 2015 (All day), 
        Thursday, November 26, 2015 (All day), 
        Friday, November 27, 2015 (All day)
Location : Blacksburg, VA
```

I am new to php and DOM and I would sincerely appreciate help in this code. This is what I have so far

```
<?php

$rss    = simplexml_load_file('http://www.example.com/feeds/events.xml');
$html   = "";
$dom    = new DOMDocument(); // the HTML parser used for descriptions' HTML

 foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
     $title         = $item->title;
     $link          = $item->link;
     $description   = $item->description;

     foreach ($description as $desc)
    {
        $dom->loadHTML($desc);
        $html = simplexml_import_dom($dom)->body;
        // ?????
    }        

     $html .= "Title : $title <br /> Link : $link <br /> Description : $description <br /> Date : <br /> Location : <hr>";
}    
echo $html;

?>
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$xmlfile='http://www.example.com/feeds/events.xml';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlfile) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    foreach($xml->children() as $item)
    {
     $title         = $item->title;
     $link          = $item->link;
     $description   = $item->description;
     $description   = $item->description;

             foreach ($description as $desc)
             {
              $title1         = $desc->title;
              $link 1         = $desc->link;
              $description1   = $desc->description;
             }   

    }
```

or

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->load($xmlfile);

// this will also output doctype and comments at top level
foreach($document->childNodes as $node)
    $result .= $document->saveXML($node)."\n";

echo $result;
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I don't see how this code will achieve the end result. The code here doesn't consider the nested div tags, which is the main problem here. Would you mind sharing your logic ?

Answer (score 0):

Using `simplexml`, `DOMDocument` and `XPath`

```
$rss    = simplexml_load_file('http://www.example.com/feeds/events.xml');

foreach($rss->channel->item as $item){

    print 'Title: ' . $item->title . PHP_EOL;
    print 'Link: ' . $item->link . PHP_EOL;

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($item->description);

    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

    $description = $xpath->query("//div[contains(@class, 'field-name-body')]");
    print 'Description: ' . $description->item(0)->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;

    $date = $xpath->query("//div[contains(@class, 'field-name-field-date')]");
    print 'Date: ' . $date->item(0)->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;

    $location = $xpath->query("//div[contains(@class, 'field-name-field-location')]/div/div");
    print 'Location: ' . $location->item(0)->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;   
}
/*
will output

Title: Thanksgiving Break 2015
Link: http://www.example.com/event/42811211
Description: Happy Holidays.
Date: Date: Wednesday, November 25, 2015 (All day)Thursday, November 26, 2015 (All day)Friday, November 27, 2015 (All day)
Location: Blacksburg, VA

*/
```

Comment: That did the job ! Thank you so much.